# Netplan eth and Wi-Fi in bond then bridge ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, network-manager

Trying to setup a network bond and then use that bond in a bridge with netplan. The bond appears correctly under proc but pulling the ethernet doesn't cause a failover to the Wi-Fi. My netplan config file is as follows:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp1s0:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: no
  wifis:
    wlp2s0:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: no
      access-points:
        "<removed>":
          password: "<removed>"
      regulatory-domain: 'GB'
  bonds:
    bond0:
      dhcp4: no
      interfaces:
        - enp1s0
        - wlp2s0
      parameters:
        mode: active-backup
        fail-over-mac-policy: none
        primary-reselect-policy: always
        primary: enp1s0
        mii-monitor-interval: 100
        min-links: 1
  vlans:
    vlan0:
      id: 0
      link: bond0
  bridges:
    br0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      interfaces:
        - bond0
      mtu: 1500
      addresses:
        - '192.168.1.84/24'
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 192.168.1.1
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.1.1
      parameters:
        forward-delay: 4
```

If I don't use the bridge and just configure the system with a bond it will come up correctly and will function as expected i.e unplugging the eth forces the connection onto Wi-Fi and then switches back once eth is restored. But as when I set the bridge to use bond0 the failover no longer works and the interface is only pingable when ethernet is plugged in.

```
$ cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0
Ethernet Channel Bonding Driver: v6.2.0-37-generic

Bonding Mode: fault-tolerance (active-backup)
Primary Slave: enp1s0 (primary_reselect always)
Currently Active Slave: enp1s0
MII Status: up
MII Polling Interval (ms): 100
Up Delay (ms): 0
Down Delay (ms): 0
Peer Notification Delay (ms): 0

Slave Interface: enp1s0
MII Status: up
Speed: 1000 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: 8c:04:ba:9c:3c:4f
Slave queue ID: 0

Slave Interface: wlp2s0
MII Status: up
Speed: Unknown
Duplex: Unknown
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: 40:5b:d8:59:7a:fb
Slave queue ID: 0
```

I have tried switching from networkd to NetworkManager, tried with and without a VLAN config. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Try turning off DHCP for your interfaces and turn it on the for the bridge

Comment: No that didn't help, same behavior. Removing the eth0 and the wi-fi doesn't take over